# c# performance and possible optimization

Tags: c#, performance

We have pretty interesting effect in a small test app, which we cannot explain.

We have the code block:

```
while (true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1920; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1080; j++)
        {
            //l += rand.Next(j);
            l += matcher.Next(j);
        }
    }
    k++;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Iteration {1}, l: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), k, l);
    l = 0;
    handle.WaitOne(100);
}
```

And the class Matcher does only a single thing on its `Next(j)` call. It returns its internally created Random object's `Next(j)` method (so, we're adding a simple function call).

Here's the Matcher class definition:

```
class Matcher
{
    private Random rand = new Random();

    internal int Next(int j)
    {
        return rand.Next(j);
    }
}
```

When we execute this code a single iteration takes around 6 seconds on Intel Core 2 Quad.
However, if we comment the line `l += matcher.Next(j);` and will uncomment the line `l += rand.Next(j);` the single iteration starts taking around the second.

Does anyone have any ideas why that happens?

Comment: NOTE: This is just a very simple test. The actual logic in the function would be more sophisticated

Comment: Did you enable optimizations (release config) to run your tests?

Comment: When you invoke `matcher.Next(j)`, is it reinstantiating a random object each time?

Comment: Can you post the code from the `Matcher` class as well?

Comment: There must be something else going on, because I can't reproduce your results based on the code you've shown/described. Please post your `Matcher` code.

Comment: Yep, filling in the minimum needed to make this runnable, I get about the same times either way. Doing an obvious performance fail (specifically, coding `Matcher.Next` to instantiate a new `Random`) I get poor performance, but nobody would do that. Even locking on `Matcher.Next` (uncontested) I get close to the first case. We really need more info to answer this.

Comment: @vc74: Yes, the code is compiled with optimization

Comment: @SteveWortham: I edited the post. The matcher class is in the post.

Comment: @JonHanna: Jon, my friend has the same time too. And this time is MUCH LOWER (about 242ms) instead of my 6 seconds and the code is running on  slower machine. So, this is definitely something about my computer or JITter settings.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just a simple function call, it's also a dereference of the internal rand object that take place in there. JIT compiler can optimize your loop a lot when you call next random directly, but not when it's inside another class.

The function is called more than 2,000,000 times, and it takes three microseconds to evaluate. It's not the fastest function in the world, but it's not overly slow either: it's the multiplication effect that kills the performance.

If matcher is not locking, or if it's OK to create multiple copies of it, you can speed it up by parallelizing your algorithm, say, eight-way for your Core2-Quad. The code should finish in under a second.

Comment: One extra (possibly hoistable) dereference and one inlineable call (the simplest possible to make the OPs code runable is within inlining size limits) isn't enough to add 2.5µs per call unless they're running it on a ZX81 or something. Even without hoisting or inlining it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the extra call takes some time (the short answer :P). Why it is 6 times as much is hard to say. When looking at performance, you'd be better off looking at the generated IL (use ILSpy, for instance) as the compiler may optimize in one situation and may not be able to optimize in the other.

In the end one line of C# may compile to different IL instructions, or even be translated to different native code (so run faster on your machine but slower on another). In some cases the garbage collector may even be the cause of the difference.

Comment: It might be quite obvious from the C# alone, if we could see the C#.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK.  Be sure to run this in release mode, as that can make a big difference.  Also, I've even seen the platform target setting have a major effect on certain low-level operations.  So try both x86 and x64.

I've got it set up to run in release mode for "Any CPU" with "Optimize Code" on, and it's running in 39 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Community, thank you very much for all your help.
The problem was: I was running that from the VS2010 with enabled IntelliTrace: Events & Calls, not Events Only. That was a simple explanation.